# how do I use Rspec to check if something is an Array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, rspec

I tried the following and got the associated error:

```
Failure/Error: reminders_array.should be_an(Array)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `should' for #<Array:0x0000000202c9a0>
```

reminders_array should be an Array and I would like to check for it with an Rspec test.  How should I do it differently from the tested assertion above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`should` is old syntax, you should do like this:

```
expect(reminders_array).to be_an(Array)
```

or:

```
expect(reminders_array).to be_an_instance_of(Array)
```

You can get more info from [rspec-expectations](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations)

Comment: yes, I tried it and still got an error showing it above.

Comment: @Angela It is impossible, can you show the full error stack?

Comment: it works now, it wasn't working when I first tried the same thing without should....well, I guess it's working then, thanks.